# how to get the count of each group in a column ignoring the null values

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

am trying to get the count of each group in a column ignoring the null values.

dataset:

```
    A   B   C
1   null    12
1   xx  13
1   yy  14
2   xx  15
2   yy  16
2   zz  12
3   xx  12
3   null    12
3   null    12
```

expected output:

```
A    B
1    2
2    3
3    1
```

code used : `df.groupby(['A'])["b"].apply(lambda x: x.notnull().count())`

Comment: when i use df.groupby(['A'])["b"].count() it gives me expected output

Comment: without nulls ?  @erentknn

Comment: am sure that will give you the count including the null as well

Comment: yes, it returns exactly what you want

Comment: can you check on the updated dataset ? @erentknn

Comment: still same result, with column C added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224436/discussion-between-erentknn-and-pylearner).

Answer (score 1):

The pandas library has a builtin pair of functions that can count the number of items in a group that has been created via the `.groupby()` method. There should be no need to use the `.apply()` method OR the lambda your code has.

from pandas import DataFrame

```
data = [[1,   None,  12],
        [1,   'xx',  13],
        [1,   'yy',  14],
        [2,   'xx',  15],
        [2,   'yy',  16],
        [2,   'zz',  12],
        [3,   'xx',  12],
        [3,   None,  12],
        [3,   None,  12]]

df = DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

## COUNT

Count will count rows that are non-null.

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['A'])['B'].count()

Out[11]: 
A
1    2
2    3
3    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

## SIZE

Size, on the other hand will count all elements of the group, regardless of whether there are non-null values or not.

```
In [12]: df.groupby(['A'])['B'].size()

Out[12]: 
A
1    3
2    3
3    3
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.groupby("A").count()
```